# Why failing to setup Gmail of 2-step verification phone based in Thunderbird?

Tags: debian, thunderbird, gmail, 2-factor-authentication

It work previously but not anymore in Fig. 1. 
I tried 5 times. 
It went through the normal Google 2-step verification process, but when returning to the main window, it gives the result in Fig. 1. 
I have another email account also in Thunderbird so this is my second email account that I would like to put in the program.

Fig. 1 Error

[image]

I succeeded to setup the account in Evolution. 
Maybe, the second email account in the same program (Thunderbird) is the problem here. 
I noticed that Evolution triggered two Google 2-step-authentication password windows open at the same time, but Thunderbird did not. So it may be a bug on the Google side.

OS: Debian 9.1
Email program: Thunderbird default

Comment: You tried checking for typos in **all** of the settings including password & user name?

Comment: @bu5hman Yes, no typos there. - - I noticed that Evolution triggered two Google 2-step-authentication password windows at the same time, but Thunderbird did not. So it may be a bug on the Google side.

Comment: I just deleted and re-registered a gmail account in Thunderbird and had no issues. I suspect you are right wrt our friends at Google. It may also be a connection issue triggering Google security / paranoia.